# Why List is not filled with n number of records and x number of dates, 2 differen records per date, until all dates are used? C#

Tags: c#, list

```
int dateOffset = 0;
DateTimeOffset currentDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
do
{
    int sameDayCount = 0;
    do
    {
        for (int record = 0; record < List.Count; record++)
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.Name = List[record].Name;
            client.Date = currentDate.AddDays(dateOffset);
            List2.Add(client);
            sameDayCount += 1;
        }
    } while (sameDayCount < 2);
    dateOffset += 1;
} while (dateOffset < 30);
```

The above is the code I wrote thanks to my modest knowledge about and experience with the C# language.
As you may expect it does not work as expected.

I need to populate the `List2` with data from the `List` and additional element -`DateTime`.

Basically I want to schedule the names of clients for 30 days, two per day.

In the code i wrote I was hoping that `do{} while (sameDayCount < 2);` will work, but the `sameDayCount += 1;` is inside the `for` loop and `do{} while` actually waits for the `for` loop to finish (when it reaches `record == List.Count`). Anyway, the `for` loop will start over from `record = 0` and I need it to go on from the last point it was left out when reached 2 records per day.

Any idea how I could resolve the problem?

So there are:

> a List with finite number of records (Client's names)
>
> 30 days to be asssigned along with records
>
> there must be two different records for each date
>
> list with records must be re-read from the place it was left off
>
> when the list is fully iterated(b=List.Count), it starts over again from b=0
>
> the whole loop ends when 30th day is reached.

in few words, seen that my question is not clear at all.
Lets say first list contains 5 clients(the number may vary).
I want to populate second list with those 5 clients + 7 days.
I want the second list to become like:

> day1 - client1, client2
>
> day2 - client3, client4
>
> day3 - client5, client1
>
> day4 - client2, client3
>
> day5 - client4, client5
>
> day6 - client1, client2
>
> day7 - client3, client4

Comment: You could do this really easily with LINQ in one line.

Comment: Please rename your variables so they're less cryptic. What do `s`, `t` and `b` represent in real-world terms?

Comment: can you explain bit more maccettura? I heard of LINQ and did something but I am not sure if that is what I think it is.

Comment: @Dai they are only  helper numbers for the loop

Comment: @positiveperspective If I understand you correctly, you have a list of objects, and you need to make a new list of objects that is an exact copy of the first list, but with a modified DateTime property?

Comment: @positiveperspective For example, you said you want to "schedule for 30 days" and I see that `s` is constrained to `0 <= s < 30`, so perhaps rename `s` to `days`?

Comment: @Dai I did the corrections as you suggested

Comment: @positiveperspective Thank you, your code is considerably easier to follow now.

Comment: @maccettura Rather than that, I want to create a list2 that consists of list1 objects and Date. In reality, the second list will contain all the records from the first list, but they will be more than once probably, as the number of records is less than 30 days.

Comment: It is not clear to me what 2 records per day means. Do you want to schedule 2 cilents per day or the same client twice per day or all the clients twice per day? And why do you need a copy (in the case you want to schedule 2 clients per day)? Couldn't you assign the dates to the clients in the existing list?

Comment: two clients per day, thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one for-loop only by stepping by 2

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

for (int i = 0; i < List.Count && i < 60; i += 2) {
    AddClient(i, currentDate);
    if (i + 1 < List.Count) {
        AddClient(i + 1, currentDate);
    }
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
}

void AddClient(int clientIndex, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var client = new Client {
        Name = List[clientIndex].Name,
        Date = dateTime
    };
    List2.Add(client);
}
```

You don't need a loop for the 30 days. Just loop until the clients run out (`i < List.Count`) or you have scheduled 60 clients, i.e., until you have reached 30 days. In case the number of clients is odd, `i + 1 < List.Count` makes sure that you don't exceed the list.

---

If you want to be more flexible with the count of clients per day, use 2 loops. One which loops through the source list in steps of `ClientsPerDay` and one which loops the `ClientsPerDay`:

```
const int ClientsPerDay = 2;
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

for (int i = 0; i < List.Count && i < ClientsPerDay * 30; i += ClientsPerDay) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ClientsPerDay; j++) {
        int clientIndex = i + j;
        if (clientIndex < List.Count) {
            var client = new Client {
                Name = List[clientIndex].Name,
                Date = currentDate
            };
            List2.Add(client);
        }
    }
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

As an alternative you could calculate the loop count in advance with

```
int clientCount = Math.Min(List.Count, ClientsPerDay * 30);
for (int i = 0; i < clientCount; i += ClientsPerDay) {
   ...
}
```

---

**Starting over**
You have changed the question in the meantime. If you want start over with the clients if the number of days is not reached but the clients run out, you can use the [modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator) (`%`) to make the indexes start over.

```
const int ClientsPerDay = 2, NumDays = 30;
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
for (int i = 0; i < ClientsPerDay * NumDays; i += ClientsPerDay) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ClientsPerDay; j++) {
        int clientIndex = (i + j) % List.Count; // clientIndex = [0 .. List.Count - 1]
        var client = new Client {
            Name = List[clientIndex].Name,
            Date = date
        };
        List2.Add(client);
    }
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

See also: [Circular array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-array/) on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/).

Comment: I didn't even know you can do omething like this with for loop. thank you Olivier, your answer is more clear than my question was.

Comment: you actually open my prehistoric mind to the possibilities of writing the code with sharp. thank you

Comment: Little correction: It must be `&&` not `||` in the loop condition. We want to stop when one condition is reached OR when the other is reached, which means that the loop can only continue when both are met (AND).

Comment: knowing that I can use two conditions in for loop gives me more playground now. thank you

Comment: the only thing is the loop from your code finishes when the total number of clients is reached. I need to loop until the 30 days are reached by continuing with same clients. I shall learn from your code and do modifications so it works for me.

Comment: hello, check this question and see how I added couple of lines to your code so the list gets populated until all dates are reached. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753415/why-does-the-list-contain-only-the-same-date-equal-to-currentdate-datetime-now

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I understand the question - so here is what I suggest you do:
First, loop over the Client's names only once.
Inside that loop, nest a second loop, counting from 0 to 59. 
In that loop, add the clients to the target list, adding the inner loop counter % 30 days to the current datetime value:

```
// meaningful names - i is kinda "defacto standard" as a for loop counter
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
{
    // using j for nesting loops is also kinda "defacto standard"
    for(int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
    {
        // you already know it's a client, use var!
        var client = new Client();
        client.Name = List[record].Name;
        client.Date = currentDate.AddDays(j % 30);
        List2.Add(client);
    }
}
```

Of course, there are more advanced solutions for this kind of thing like using linq - but I'm not sure I'm comfortable suggesting linq to a c# beginner - I think it's better to start with the basics and work your way up to advanced stuff.

Comment: I didn't see any reference to a month, the question clearly states 30 days, though I agree it's not the easiest question to understand.

Answer (score 0):

as Olivier Jacot-Descombes suggested:

```
const int ClientsPerDay = 2;
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

for (int i = 0; i < List.Count && i < ClientsPerDay * 30; i += ClientsPerDay) {
for (int j = 0; j < ClientsPerDay; j++) {
    int clientIndex = i + j;
    if (clientIndex < List.Count) {
        var client = new Client {
            Name = List[clientIndex].Name,
            Date = currentDate
        };
        List2.Add(client);
    }
}
currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
```

}

But this goes until the List.Count is reached. So it populates the list only until the clients are all used.
Instead, I am looking for a solution that will loop the same Clients until 30 day limit is reached.
Something like this:

```
do
{
const int ClientsPerDay = 2;
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

for (int i = 0; i < List.Count && i < ClientsPerDay * 30; i += ClientsPerDay) {
for (int j = 0; j < ClientsPerDay; j++) {
    int clientIndex = i + j;
    if (clientIndex < List.Count) {
        var client = new Client {
            Name = List[clientIndex].Name,
            Date = currentDate
        };
        List2.Add(client);
    }
}
currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
}
} while (currentDate < currentdate.AddDays(30));
```

But my Do simply repeats the job instead of going on with dates.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, I guess? All dates in UTC - it's easier to work with canonical datetimes rather than using those crappy looking offsets. You can always convert them to locale when you need to show them in terminal, so there is no reason to work with them up until final point.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentDate   = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var daysInMonth   = DateTime.DaysInMonth;
        var repeats       = 2;

        for(var i = 0; i < daysInMonth;i++)
        {
            foreach(var item in List)
            {
                for(var r = 0; r < repeats;r++)
                {
                    var client = new Client
                    {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Date = currentDate.AddDays(i)
                    };
                    List2.Add(client);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**PS**: Question is really bad, I didn't understand a thing.

Comment: thank you eocron, I am studying your code as I am stillll bit sslow with calculations..

Comment: If you could suggest the change of question title I will appreciate your help

Comment: Your solution looks very simple. But isn't this code adding the same item.Name twice along with the same Date?