# Why does the List contain only the same date equal to currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date?

Tags: c#, list, datetime, for-loop

```
const int IterationsPerDay = 2;
DateTimeOffset currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
int dayCount = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < ((IterationsPerDay * 30) / ClientsList.Count); j += IterationsPerDay)
{
    for (int f = 0; f < IterationsPerDay; f++)
    {
        int iterationIndex = j + f;
        if (iterationIndex < productsOfSameCategory.Count)
        {
           Client _client = new Client();
           _client.Name = ClientsList[iterationIndex].Name;
           _client.Date = currentDate;
           VisitsList.Add(_client);
        }
        if (iterationIndex < productsOfSameCategory.Count)
        {
           Client _client = new Client();
           _client.Name = ClientsList[iterationIndex-ClientsList.Count].Name;
           _client.Date = currentDate;
           VisitsList.Add(_client);
        }

    }
    currentDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

the `VisitsList` should get all 30 dates added to it. There should be two Clients for each date so there should be 60 records in the list.

Why does the loop add only first date??

Comment: Could you please reduce your code the the smallest possible version, which still shows the problem?

Comment: ok hold on please.

Comment: I am deleting the question and post again when created program that reproduces the error

Comment: there should be two meetings per day, for 30 days, with a finite number of clients on rotation. Day1 - client1, client2, Day2 - client3, client1, Day3 - client2, client3, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest go through post for the same : [**DateTime is immutable**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2012/03/datetime-is-immutable.html)

as the date is struct type i.e value type and its immutable , you need to do like this

```
currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
//above line store new data to to your currentdate variable with olddate+1
```